Assignment and comparison of class properties without boxing
Consider the following scenario:
public interface ICloneable<T>:
    ICopyable<T> where T : ICloneable<T>, new()
{
    public T CloneTyped ();
}

public interface ICopyable<T>
    where T : ICopyable<T>
{
    public T CopyTo (T other);
    public T CopyFrom (T other);
}

public interface IDirtyable<T>
    where T : IDirtyable<T>
{
    // Compares the current object [this] to an unaltered object [referenceObject].
    public bool IsDirty (T referenceObject);
}

public partial class Model:
    ICloneable<Model>,
    ICopyable<Model>,
    IDirtyable<Model>
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateTimeModified { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Model CloneTyped () => new Model().CopyFrom(this);
    public Model CopyFrom (Model other) => other.CopyTo(this);

    public Model CopyTo (Model other)
    {
        other.Id = this.Id;
        other.DateTimeCreated = this.DateTimeCreated;
        other.DateTimeModified = this.DateTimeModified;
        other.Name = this.Name;

        return (other);
    }

    public bool IsDirty (Model referenceObject)
    {
        return
            this.Id == referenceObject.Id
            && this.DateTimeCreated == referenceObject.DateTimeCreated
            && this.DateTimeModified == referenceObject.DateTimeModified
            && this.Name == referenceObject.Name;
    }
}

Please note that for the sake of this question, I am not interested in INotifyPropertyChanged or other similar mechanisms. Furthermore, assume that the class Model has dozens of scalar properties (we do not care about composite types).
So we are left with an interface pattern that performs a comparison or assignment operation on two objects of the same type. Now, since I know the list of properties that should be processed by these interface implementations, I could do something like the following:
    public bool IsDirtyUsingReflection (Model referenceObject)
    {
        var equal = true;
        var propertyNames = new [] { nameof(this.Id), nameof(this.DateTimeCreated), nameof(this.DateTimeModified), nameof(this.Name), };
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            equal
                &= property.GetValue(this)
                ?.Equals(property.GetValue(referenceObject))
                ?? false;

            if (!equal) { return (true); }
        }

        return (false);
    }

So, the question is, how could I maintain a list of properties and compare/assign them without reflection or boxing?
I thought about maintaining such properties as Expression types.
var properties = new Expression<Func<T, object?>> [] {...};

Any guidance would be appreciated to achieve the following:

Maintain a static list of properties.
Perform assignment and comparison operations without boxing.
Perform assignment and comparison operations without reflection.
Maintain a list of Expression objects or compiled lambdas that avoid boxing. Compilation and/or boxing at a type-level (static1) is fine.

The data types to be considered only include built-in value types, string, enums, and structs that implement IEquitable.

Expression generation or raw ref-emit (ILGenerator) are indeed viable, however: I wonder whether a better approach here would be to write a Roslyn code generator to do this for you. For example, you could write:
public partial class Model
{
    public partial bool IsDirty (Model referenceObject);
}

and the generator could detect that and output the missing half based on the members discovered during build:
partial class Model
{
    public partial bool IsDirty (Model referenceObject)
    {
        return
            this.Id == referenceObject.Id
            && this.DateTimeCreated == referenceObject.DateTimeCreated
            && this.DateTimeModified == referenceObject.DateTimeModified
            && this.Name == referenceObject.Name;
    }
}

A bit more work, perhaps, but it can be more flexible and performant in the long run - it is very hard to maintain expression / ref-emit code (ask me how I know...), where-as making tweaks to generator output: simple.

Thank you. My scenario already involves code generation, where the application takes a custom data model and generates data, business, and UI layers. I use Roslyn heavily; in fact, some of the generated code also includes code generators. While I agree that code-generators are easier to maintain in the long run, I am driven by curiosity and try different implementations for myself to learn those lessons. I would love to know a bit more about what you u refer to with Expression generation or raw ref-emit. Could you point me to some resources that you found useful to explore this path?

And, of course, I had to ask... I know of your work on redis and protobuf among others. Am curious to know what role reflection, expressions and ref-emit played and where.

Protobuf-net is basically all runtime ref-emit; it is a nightmare to maintain :)  sorry, I don't have good resources - I had to dig the hard way, mostly using tools like reflector, sharplab.io, or ildasm - figure out what the IL should look like, and then: emit that. Kevin Montrose has a good IL helper library ("sigil") - which makes it easier to get right (rather than just seeing the dreaded invalid program exception). Expression is fairly well documented, but the trick there is to write an expression lambda in pure C#, compile it, decompile it (sharplab.io is great for this), and read it

Example of what I mean re expression and sharplab: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjpQKIIAOsAzl7RPVwDchNpxg8+9ADwYArFIYAXADRLlFYgD5NpGByikAvIVKnSACgTLSATwCUhnZYDU9ygBUIAZUVQGAc3M7QSA==
